# How do you configure pypi under Windows?

Tags: windows, pypi

On my Mac, *nix based systems I configure pip by modifying the files:

- `~/.pypirc`
- `~/.pip/pip.conf`

The documentation that I've found so far, says that under windows you need to set the HOME environment variable and place the files in:

- `%HOME%\.pypirc`
- `%HOME%\pip\pip.conf`

However, this doesn't seem to work for me and when I try to use pip to install a package from one of our alternate servers the package can't be found.  Any suggestions?

Links I've found so far

- https://pypi.python.org/pypi/devpi-server/0.8 (see section on
  permanent pip configuration)
- http://www.pip-installer.org/en/latest/configuration.html (see
  section on config file)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wasn't able to pip to use my mirror repos ***auto-magically*** just by setting up my configuration files, but I was able to use the repositories by using the -i option:

```
pip install -i http://url.to.my.repository package_name
```

Answer (score 11):

The [pip configuration docs](https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/user_guide/#configuration) at PyPA tell you to use a `pip.ini` file stored either:

1. Globally at `C:\ProgramData\pip\` (Win7 and up), or
2. per-user at `%HOME%\pip\` or
3. per-virtualenv at the virtualenv root

In case of multiple pip.ini files, per-user settings override global settings. See the docs for more details.

Comment: I think this answers the title question "How to configure PYPI on Windows" better than the accepter answer, but the accepted one answers the question on how to install from a custom repo (which is only a small part of the PYPI configuration.)

Comment: The (assumable later updtated) pip config docs mentioned in your answer now says in regard to per-user configuration:

"On Windows the configuration file is ``%APPDATA%\pip\pip.ini``", but that the ``%HOME%\pip\pip.ini`` is a legacy location.

Comment: Also, that "You can set a custom path location for this config file using the environment variable `PIP_CONFIG_FILE`"

Comment: FWIW, I was able to figure out what pip.ini files already were expected to exist by this accepted answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36569511/is-it-possible-to-get-pip-to-print-the-configuration-it-is-using , and when I discovered that none of them existed I created one using your answer.

Comment: What about .pypirc? Can that configuration be placed inside of pip.ini?!

Comment: for me, my pip.ini file locate at C:\Users\{{username}}\AppData\Roaming\pip

Comment: This is confusing. Should it be `.pypirc` or `pip.ini`?

Answer (score 10):

I was trying to work out where to put .pypirc on my Windows installation and the answer was  `C:\Users\YourName\.pypirc`.  Thanks Ernst Haagsman https://blog.jetbrains.com/pycharm/2017/05/how-to-publish-your-package-on-pypi/

Answer (score 7):

I had a problem with this in Windows using `setup.py`. Getting the error:

> ```
> ValueError: <repository> not found in .pypirc
> ```

From this I found that [`distutils` only uses `~/.pypirc`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.6/Lib/distutils/config.py#L40). And so you need to make the file `%USERPROFILE%/.pypirc`.

Answer (score 2):

the easiest way to locate the folder is by running the following command in the cmd.

```
pip config -v list
```

That will result with the paths that pip is searching in to find the config file.

Answer (score 2):

actually use:

```bash
pip config debug
```

to get all the locations and config details listed.
try it out!