# Why is Twine 1.9.1 still uploading to legacy PyPi?

Tags: python, pypi, twine

I want to upload packages to pypi.org as mentioned in the [Migrating to PyPI.org](https://packaging.python.org/guides/migrating-to-pypi-org/) documentation, but Twine uploads to `https://upload.pypi.org/legacy/`.

It's available on [pypi.python.org/pypi/mypolr](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/mypolr), but is not found on [pypi.org](https://pypi.org/search/?q=mypolr).

I've tried to read 
several other questions, tutorials, and guides.

My pip.ini-file (I'm on Windows 10) looks like this:

```
[distutils]
index-servers =
    pypi

[pypi]
```

I don't have my username or password stored, so the [pypi] section is empty (as mentioned in migration docs).

I've put the .ini-file in my user folder, and confirmed ([per this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36569511/is-it-possible-to-get-pip-to-print-the-configuration-it-is-using)) that it's actually using the one I've set (using environment variable `PIP_CONFIG_FILE`).

Afraid that I had got something wrong, I also tried without a pip.ini-file to make Twine use its defaults.

I'm using Python 3.6.3 (from Anaconda), and my tools' versions are:

- Twine 1.9.1 (migration docs says it should be 1.8+)
- setuptools 38.2.3 (migration docs says it should be 27+)

Whether or not it's relevant, here is some more info:

- Link to my [setup.py](https://github.com/fauskanger/mypolr/blob/d5483b6e57137e39336b2a8ffc983b4524bc8a6e/setup.py)
- `setup` is imported from `setuptools` and not `distutils.core`
- [README.rst](https://github.com/fauskanger/mypolr/blob/d5483b6e57137e39336b2a8ffc983b4524bc8a6e/README.rst) is used as `long description`, but in the [PyPi page](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/mypolr) only first 8 asterix of header is shown. (Compare [this](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/mypolr) with [this](https://github.com/fauskanger/mypolr/blob/d5483b6e57137e39336b2a8ffc983b4524bc8a6e/README.rst))
- The package I upload is version is 0.2.1 (at the time of posting this)
- `setuptools_scm` is used to fetch versions from git tags
- build is made with `python setup.py sdist bdist_wheel`

Please let me know if there is any other information that could be useful to figure this out.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You appear to be doing everything correctly.  Twine is not uploading via legacy PyPI (https://pypi.python.org).  It is uploading to the new PyPI (https://pypi.org, a.k.a. "Warehouse") via the original (and so far only) PyPI API, and this API just happens to be named "legacy".

Also, your package is present on Warehouse at https://pypi.org/project/mypolr/; Warehouse search is apparently not production-ready.

Comment: Wow, that is amazing, and thanks a lot. If I understand correctly then Twine is set up correctly to work with pypi.org, and it's just that pypi.org is not "ready" yet.

Comment: it's weird that Twine STILL, today, tells me it's uploading to legacy, while I can find my package (pymcs) in the Warehouse on pypy.org? Very confusing.

Comment: @K.-MichaelAye: Because "legacy" is still the one and only API.

Comment: but isn't that an incorrect confusing wording? It then should be saying "using legacy API to upload to current warehouse" or something to that effect?

Answer (score 6):

The docs for Warehouse explain this confusing nomenclature. Quotes below are from the [front page](https://warehouse.pypa.io/) and from the page about the [Legacy API](https://warehouse.pypa.io/api-reference/legacy/):

> Warehouse is a [web application](https://github.com/pypa/warehouse) that implements the canonical [Python package index (repository)](https://packaging.python.org/glossary/#term-package-index); its production deployment is [PyPI](https://pypi.org/). It replaces an older code base that powered pypi.python.org.

> ## Legacy API
>
> The “Legacy API” provides feature parity with [pypi-legacy](https://pypi.python.org/), hence the term “legacy”.
>
> ...
>
> ### Upload API
>
> The API endpoint served at upload.pypi.org/legacy/ is Warehouse’s emulation of the legacy PyPI upload API. This is the endpoint that tools such as [twine](https://twine.readthedocs.io/) and [distutils](https://docs.python.org/3.7/distutils/packageindex.html#the-upload-command) use to [upload distributions to PyPI](https://packaging.python.org/tutorials/distributing-packages/).

In other words, as I understand it:

- PyPI was once a web application hosted at pypi.python.org. That old application, which no longer runs, is now referred to by the name *pypi-legacy*.
- PyPI is now a web application hosted at pypi.org. This new application is named *Warehouse*. The old pypi.python.org is now just a redirect to pypi.org.
- In addition to some new endpoints, *Warehouse* still exposes a couple of API endpoints that *pypi-legacy* used to have. Because these endpoints were copied across from *pypi-legacy*, they are together known as the "Legacy API".
- In addition to that, the upload endpoint within *Warehouse*'s Legacy API is served from the URL path `/legacy`, a naming choice which again reflects the fact that it is a (partial) reimplementation of the endpoint used for uploads in *pypi-legacy*.

This all seems more confusing than it needs to be, but it is what it is.

Comment: to me `legacy` implies `deprecated` and so i worry that there will be a new one soon --> **HOWEVER** according to this post **there is only one API** and there are **no future plans to create a new one or deprecate the existing `legacy`**. so `legacy` is more a name instead an adjective/description.

Answer (score 2):

In case anyone else is coming here from google, mystified why their uploads are failing, don't forget to check https://status.python.org/ to make sure there isn't an outage. Sometimes you just gotta wait :p

Comment: Great point, it's currently under maintenance – it's not just me